# I am unable to acquire the newest version of pip

Tags: python, pip

When I try to upgrade my pip, using the command prompt, to the newest version I get the errors in the picture below. Is there an administrative step I have overlooked?

An image of my command prompt is located at this link (I don't have a reputation of 10 which is required to include images).
[image]

```
C:\Users\hassa>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |################################| 1.3MB 455kB/s

Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:

Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pip' -> 'C:\\Users\\hassa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uazegy0h-uninstall\\program files\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pip'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 550, in move
    rmtree(src)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 488, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 383, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 381, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\basecommand.py'

You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\hassa>
____________________________________
```

Comment: Do you have any running Python processes? Try opening Task Manager and killing and running Python processes and then try again.

Comment: Looks like its getting a permission error, try running the shell as an admin.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using Anaconda. You should use the `conda` command to update pip in that case:

```
conda update pip
```

If that doesn't work, try opening your `cmd.exe` as Administrator and try again.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have worked, but I seem to have ran into a permissions issue. I received the following error after utilizing "conda update pip":

Comment: CondaIOError: IO error: Missing write permissions in: C:\Program Files\Anaconda3
#
# You don't appear to have the necessary permissions to update packages
# into the install area 'C:\Program Files\Anaconda3'.
# However you can clone this environment into your home directory and
# then make changes to it.
# This may be done using the command:
#
# $ conda create -n my_root --clone=C:\Program Files\Anaconda3

Comment: I haven't used Conda all that much, so you might need to ask them about that error. However I suspect one way around it would be to open `cmd.exe` as Administrator and try running it again. However you may have other permission issues since Program Files usually requires Admin privileges to access.